# OpenCV: Check whether cv::Point has been set a value

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to write a program similar to below:

```
cv::Point keyPoint
keyPoint = outputOfFunction(); // Return value is not set to anything if no valid results.

if( //keyPoint was set by the function above... ){
  // Do something with this value
else{
  // Do nothing
}
```

However cv::Point does not have a member function similar to empty().

What is the best way to implement the above?

I don't really want outputOfFunction() to return a point if it doesn't have a valid result... it seems kind of clumsy to do that.

Comment: If you design `outputOfFunction()` (assuming it's yours) like that then a Point will *have* to be created regardless. Are you in control of `outputOfFunction`? If so, why not use a signature like this:
`bool outputOfFunction( cv::Point& )` where inside that function you set the variable passed in if everything goes well. And you return true if everything is good.

Comment: That worked really well, thanks for that! (I'm relatively new to programming). One question, does coding something like this make the code hard for other people to understand?

Comment: In C++, functions of that format are pretty common in APIs. Windows API is a prime example, but there are many many others. It doesn't make it hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of possible options:

1) passing by reference and returning bool if the value is valid

```
bool f(cv::Point &p);
```

2) returning some fixed value on failure, like cv::Point(-1,1)

3) returning boost::optional:

```
boost::optional<cv::Point> f();

auto might_be_point = f();
if (might_be_point.is_initalized())
    cv::Point point = might_be_point.get();
```

4) throwing an exception on failure:

```
class my_logic_exception: public std::exception { }

cv::Point f() {
   if (sth_goes_wrong)
        throw my_logic_exception;
   // ...
}
```

In general I would suggest 3) or 4).

Comment: Wow very detailed, this is really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. One option is as Rollen D'Souza suggested in the comments, to return a `bool` and pass a `cv::Point` by reference.

In some cases there are certain return values that could not be valid in the particular domain. For example, say your `cv::Point` must be a valid coordinate within the image, i.e. the coordinates must be positive (and less than the width/height). In these cases you can return such an invalid value to indicate failure, e.g. `cv::Point(-1,-1)`.